# Porque mi programa funciona bien si lo corro en el IDE pero ya ejecutado en un exe no

Tags: java, excel, properties

Tengo un programa en java que una de sus funciones es hacer un reporte en excel, cuando lo hago corriendo el programa desde el IDE (eclipse) me funciona bien pero ya al hacer el .jar y luego el .exe ya no me funciona (no me da el archivo), y lo mismo me pasa con otra función que cambia los datos de un archivo .properties que uso para la configuración del programa (colores, fuentes, datos de conexión, impresoras, etc.) y este no se modifica

Este es el codigo de mi reporte en excel

```
public static void reporte(ModeloVentas ven) {
        File archivo = new File("reporte"+ven.getFecha()+".xlsx");
       
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        
        Sheet pagina = workbook.createSheet("Reporte de productos");
       
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.AQUA.getIndex());
        style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        String[] titulos = {"ID", "Fecha","Producto", "Precio", "Usuario", "Ticket", "Complemento", "Bebida", "Cliente", "Metodo", "Total", "Pago", "Cambio"};       
        
        Row fila = pagina.createRow(0);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++) {
            
            Cell celda = fila.createCell(i);
            
            celda.setCellStyle(style);
            celda.setCellValue(titulos[i]);
        }
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        ResultSet rs;
        PreparedStatement ps1=null;
        ResultSet rs1;
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT ID, fecha, producto, precio, usuario, ticket, complemento, bebida, cliente, metodo, total, pago, cambio FROM ventas WHERE fecha = ?";
        String sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD FROM ventas WHERE fecha = ?";    
        try {
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ps1.setString(1, ven.getFecha());
            rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
             if (rs1.next()) {                 
                 System.out.println(rs1.getString("CANTIDAD"));
            }
             else{
                 System.out.println("Ningun resultado encontrado");
             }    
        } catch (SQLException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, ven.getFecha());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            int numCol = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            int i=0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                              
                     fila = pagina.createRow(i+1);               
                     for(int j = 0; j<numCol; j++) {                         
                         if(j!=3) {
                             Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                            celda.setCellValue(rs.getString(j+1));
                         }else {
                             Cell celda = fila.createCell(j);
                            celda.setCellValue(rs.getInt(j+1));
                         }   
                     }  
                     i++;
                }                   
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      
        try {
         
            FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
            
            workbook.write(salida);
           
            workbook.close();
           LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Archivo creado existosamente en {0}", archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Archivo no localizable en sistema de archivos");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Archivo no localizable en sistema de archivos");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error de entrada/salida");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de entrada/salida");
        }
    }
```

y este el que guarda mi archivo properties

```
JButton btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cbSize.setName(String.valueOf(cbSize.getSelectedItem()));
                cbColor.setName(String.valueOf(cbColor.getSelectedItem()));
                cbFondo.setName(String.valueOf(cbFondo.getSelectedItem()));
                Properties p = new Properties();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream  os = new FileOutputStream(new File("src\\modelos\\confi.properties"));
                    p.setProperty("fontSize", cbSize.getName());
                    p.setProperty("back", cbFondo.getName());
                    p.setProperty("fore", cbColor.getName());
                    p.setProperty("url", txtUrl.getText());
                    p.setProperty("usuario", String.valueOf(txtPass.getPassword()));
                    p.setProperty("password", String.valueOf(txtPassCon.getPassword()));
                    p.setProperty("printer", txtPrinter.getText());
                    p.setProperty("printer2", txtPrinter2.getText());
                    p.setProperty("combo", txtPrecio.getText());
                    p.store(os, null);
                    os.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    FileInputStream e1 = new FileInputStream(new File("src\\modelos\\confi.properties"));
                    p.load(e1);
                    Login.fontSize = p.getProperty("fontSize");
                    Login.back = p.getProperty("back");
                    Login.fore = p.getProperty("fore");
                    Login.url = p.getProperty("url");
                    Login.usuario = p.getProperty("usuario");
                    Login.password = p.getProperty("password");
                    Login.combo = p.getProperty("combo");
                    Login.printer = p.getProperty("printer");
                    Login.printer2 = p.getProperty("printer2");
                    Login.usr = p.getProperty("usr");
                    Login.pass = p.getProperty("pass");
                    e1.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {            
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {      
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }   
                
                Main.frmCon = null;
                dispose();
            }
        });
        btnGuardar.setForeground(Login.colorF);
        btnGuardar.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        btnGuardar.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnGuardar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnGuardar.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED, null, null));
        btnGuardar.setBackground(Login.colorB);
        btnGuardar.setBounds(10, 715, 230, 51);
        contentPane.add(btnGuardar);
```

Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda y su tiempo, saludos.

Comment: Y que sale en el logger?

Comment: En ambos me sale que el archivo no se encuentran cuando lo corro del ejecutable, si lo hago del IDE si jala todo bien

Comment: y si el archivo no se encuentra, porque no estamos mirando ese problema, y ver que archivo no se encuentra y porque?

Comment: De la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html): *"Un recurso (resource) son datos (imágenes, audio, texto, etc.) que necesita accesar un programa de manera independiente de la ubicación del código del programa"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema aquí es que está utilizando una referencia "relativa" para sus archivos, cuando ejecuta una clase Java desde un IDE, todo lo relacionado con la ruta está vinculado o relativo al IDE o la ubicación de su espacio de trabajo, cuando se trata de un JAR necesita preparar su código de manera que entienda que está dentro de un JAR y obtenga las ubicaciones relativas a él.

Para el archivo que está tratando de **guardar**, ni siquiera está especificando una ruta o ubicación, por lo que es completamente relativo a lo que sea que esté ejecutando su código, debe especificar una ubicación fija `C:\\carpeta\\carpeta\\archivo.xlsx` o si desea que se guarde en el mismo directorio que su jar, debe usar un código similar al siguiente para encontrar primero el directorio jar y luego concatenar este directorio con el nombre del archivo, pero **debe especificar la ruta en la que desea que se guarde el archivo**.

```
//Identifique dónde se encuentra este JAR
String path = MiClase.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
//Especifique la ruta completa para el archivo    
File archivo = new File(path + "\\" + "reporte"+ven.getFecha()+".xlsx"
```

)

El mismo principio se aplica para **leer** archivos de propiedades, no importa si están fuera o dentro de su jar, debe preparar el código como tal.
Si están fuera de su jar, debe especificar la ubicación completa `C:\\carpeta\\carpeta\\archivo.properties` o si están dentro de su jar, debe usar un código para ubicarlos, como se muestra en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815404/load-properties-file-in-jar) .